# Setting up web development envirnoment with a VM (ssh + browser testing)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx, virtual-machines

I am running VMware Fusion on my Mac (10.6) with an Ubuntu 9.10 (32 bit) VM for my development environment. How would I setup SSH to be able to SSH into the Ubuntu VM from the Mac? Also, when I am testing websites in browsers, how would I set it up so that I can go to the site on FF on the Mac and have it point to the site running on the Apache server on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the VM networking in a "bridged" mode. That way, your VM will have it's own IP address. They you access it like you would access any other server.

Comment: Thank you. Will this IP address ever change?

Comment: @Brandon, that would depend on your network.  You could set a static address or you could set a reservation on your DHCP server.